# Google Chrome Profile

Tags: google-chrome, google-account, chrome-profile, chrome-sync

I have a Google Account and I am using Google Chrome. In Chrome I have synced all my data (Bookmarks, Passwords...). Next to my Account, I have a Chrome Profile for this Account. So I got some questions.

1. Are these Profiles only local on the PC [since on a different PC with the same Google Account everything (Bookmarks, PW) is synced but not the profile (like the profile name)]?
2. What happens if I delete the profile, will it delete all my synced Data as well or only the appearance of the profile...?

Like I said I figured out that the profile is not synced to every device, However Bookmarks and PW are synced.

Can you guys please help me figure that out, I am too scared to lose data by trying. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I did some research and tried everything with a test account.

There are online profiles called the google-account and there are offline-profiles (like chrome profiles). If you sync the chrome-profile to the google-account. You can delete the chrome-profile without losing any data like (bookmarks, pw or history). If you do not sync the profile with the account you will lose this data if you delete the profile.

That means if you create a chrome-profile on a different device and sync it to the account it will affect your account if your change any bookmarks and pw... However deleting the profile does not affect them since its syned to the google-account and a delete of the profile is only local on the device u are using.

That's the reason why the name of the chrome-profiles ** are not synced** on all devices.

I hope i could answere the question good enough.

A big thanks for the help by Michael: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16659155/michael-wagner